# Input not initialized in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm building a little website in Angular and i'm facing a wall.

I got the following,

```
<app-details *ngIf="(selected | async)" [selected]="selected | async"></app-details>
```

In the parent, selected is an observable.

```
  public selected: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private store: Store<State>) { }

  ngOnInit() {;
    this.selected = this.store.pipe(select(selectSelectedChamp));
  }
```

In my child, I want to do some work on `selected` :

```
  @Input() selected: any;
  public data: Array<{
    preview: string,
    thumbnail: string,
    alt: string,
  }>
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data= this.selected.map(skin => {
      return {
        preview: ... ,
        thumbnail: ...,
        alt: ...
      }
    })
  }
```

Problem is, `selected` doesn't seems to be initalized, if I log it, it's empty, and I got an error on the map... `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`
Maybe adding the visual effect will help understanding. I want to be able to visualize image, skins and infos on different League Of legends characters on click.

On the first click, my variable is not initialized, ie. image is not displaying,
On the second click tho', image is displaying, but one click late ?
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're using `async` in the template for `selected`. Is it an observable?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to also show your code for how you use this component? You should be providing `selected` as an input.

Comment: ` this.select = this.store.pipe(select(selectSelectedChamp));` should be `this.selected...`, but I don't know if it's typo or not. Did you check what is the output when you add `tap` to stream? Something like: `this.store.pipe(select(selectSelectedChamp), tap(value -> console.log('value')));`

Comment: do you want to rerun the stuff in `ngOnInit` when `selection` changes?

Comment: There was indeed some typos.
I don't have any error on types or variable names.
The store returns the good value, it just seems to take some time to display ?
Added some details in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Change this part:

```
[champDetails]="selected | async"
```

to this:

```
[selected]="selected | async"
```

Explanation: The childs component @Input name is `selected`, so in parent you must use `[selected]=...`. Otherwise `selected` is undefined, hence the error `Cannot read property map of undefined`.

Comment: My bad, variable names are good in my code, edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<app-details *ngIf="(selected | async) as selection" [selection]="selection"></app-details>
```

```js
  @Input() selection: any;
  public data: Array<{
    preview: string,
    thumbnail: string,
    alt: string,
  }>
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.selection.pipe(take(1)).subacribe(res => {
       // Your code here...
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything. I'm still one click late

Answer (score 0):

you probably was to declare the `async` result as a template variable like so:

```
<app-details *ngIf="selected | async as selection" [selected]="selection"></app-details>
```

this way you're not subscribing multiple times, the initial value from the async pipe will always be undefined, you work around tht this way.  next, you probably want to use a setter input:

```
  private _selected;
  @Input() 
  set selected(value: any) {
    this._selected = value;
    this.data = value.map(skin => {
      return {
        preview: ... ,
        thumbnail: ...,
        alt: ...
      }
    })
  }
  get selected() {
    return this._selected
  }
```

this way, that map routine will run everytime the input value changes.

Comment: That was a good idea to avoid the double subscription in my template, I fixed it !
It didn't fix my problem though... I want to point that even if I get the data directly from the store in my child, not via an input, the problem is still present.